# Solr optimistic concurrency update: version conflict

Tags: solr, conflict

Could you please help me to understand why I have such results for optimistic concurrency update.

Say, I have the following document:

```
{
  "phrase": "some phrase",
  "id": "5d1341797e2ed599",
  "_version_": 1479312171996283000
}
```

In solrconfig.xml:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="dedupe"> 
  <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
    <bool name="enabled">true</bool> 
    <bool name="overwriteDupes">true</bool> 
    <str name="signatureField">id</str> 
    <str name="fields">phrase</str> 
    <str name="signatureClass">org.apache.solr.update.processor.Lookup3Signature</str> 
  </processor>
...
```

In schema.xml:

```
<field name="phrase" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
...
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
...
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Because I use SignatureUpdate, I can't use partial update requests containing signature field (known Solr limitation). So I try to update the documents with optimistic concurrency update.

According to the document [Optimistic Concurrency](http://heliosearch.org/solr/optimistic-concurrency/) if specify document version on an update, then the presence of the *version* field instructs Solr to accept the update only if the document version matches exactly. After the update has successfully completed, the document will have a new *version* that is guaranteed to be higher than the last.

If I send the update request (the phrase field is changed) as follows:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[  {
  "phrase": "some phrase. updated",
  "_version_": 1479312171996283000
} ]'
```

I get the conflict error:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 409,
    "QTime": 14
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "version conflict for f2adc45579faa53a expected=1479312171996283000 actual=-1",
    "code": 409
  }
}
```

Why such results?

Answer (score -1):

from [heliosearch](http://heliosearch.org/solr/optimistic-concurrency/) see explanation below

> If the client specifies a *version* that does not match what currently exists in Solr, an HTTP error with code 409 (Conflict) will be returned.

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8983/solr/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[{"id":"book1", "author":"Mr Bean", "_version_":12345}]'
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

> {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":409,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "msg":"version conflict for book1 expected=12345 actual=1408814192853516288",
    "code":409}}
```

> Note that we used the curl option -i to show the response HTTP headers to verify that this  generated an HTTP-level error in addition to the Solr-level error in the body of the response.

Comment: how do you make sure the versions match though ? What is the solution ?